# How can we do a cut and paste menu for nodes in pane using javafx not swing?

Tags: java, javafx

This is my code, for copy menu is it right ?

```
    // Copy Item
    MenuItem copy = new MenuItem("Copy");
    copy.setOnAction(e -> {

        Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
        ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();

        clipboard.setContent(content);

    });
```

Comment: Please visit this section in order to get a proper answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  I think you should try to run this code first and depending on your results then share your doubts or any error that you can get from console.  Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, But you are not copying anything.You have to set value in ClipboardContent

```
ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
content.putString(label.getText());
```

setting copy menu on label

```
ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
menu.getItems().add(copy);
label.setContextMenu(menu);
```

Comment: thank you ..then how can i get the content to past it ?

Comment: @DarinJojas https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/input/ClipboardContent.html#getString--